# How to make full domain controller with active directory?

Tags: 12.04, ldap, active-directory

How to make full domain controller with active directory that can accept windows client pc's using ubuntu LTS 12.04 desktop edition.
I need a full tutorial that show me step by step how could it be made since i got confused from those on internet since many guides that conflict each other.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you will have to follow the ubuntu server guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-ldap.html)

install dhcp,dns,ldap,kerberos and samba

Answer (score 0):

No. To the best of my knowledge you can't create a full blown Active Directory Primary Domain Controller with Ubuntu server, however a Samba server can be configured to *appear* as a Windows NT4-style domain controller. A major advantage of this configuration is the ability to centralize user and machine credentials. Samba can also use multiple backends to store the user information.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-dc.html.en